# Differentiation of a modulus function

Tags: functions, derivatives

How to find derivative of

$$f(x)=|\sin^{-1}(2x^2-1)|$$

Please provide stepwise mechanism.

The original question was to find domain of derivative of y=|arc sin(2x^2−1)|.

My METHOD- My attempt was to break y into intervals ,i.e., where \sin^{-1}(2x^2-1)>=0 and where \sin^{-1}(2x^2-1)<0,and then differentiate the resulting function and find its domain. But my teacher said that this is wrong. He argued that this is like putting values to a function(which makes it a constant) and then differentiating.For eg- If we put x=0 and then differentiate we will get y'=0 which may be wrong.Is my teacher correct?

Comment: Step 0: what have you tried so far? We don't respond well to questions at this level where the questioner shows no work.

Comment: Also, does `asin` mean $a \cdot \sin$ or $\arcsin$? There's an edit suggestion changing to the former.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $\left | x \right |=\sqrt{x^{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$|a\cdot\sin(2x^2-1)|\Longrightarrow$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(|a\cdot\sin(2x^2-1)|)=$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(|a\cdot\sin(1-2x^2)|)=$$
$$\frac{d|u|}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}=$$

(With $u=a\cdot(1-x^2)$ and $\frac{d}{du}(|u|)=\frac{u}{|u|}$)

$$\frac{a(\frac{d}{dx}(a\cdot\sin(1-2x^2)))\sin(1-2x^2)}{|a\cdot\sin(2x^2-1)|}=$$

$$a\left(\frac{d}{dx}\sin(1-2x^2)\right)\cdot\frac{a\cdot\sin(2x^2-1)}{|a\cdot\sin(2x^2-1)|}=$$

$$a\left(-4x\cos(1-2x^2)\right)\cdot\frac{a\cdot\sin(2x^2-1)}{|a\cdot\sin(2x^2-1)|}=$$

$$-\frac{2a^2x\sin(2-4x^2)}{|a\cdot\sin(1-2x^2)|}$$

Comment: You might want to explain, what happens if $\sin(1-2x^2) = 0$ :)

Comment: how is d|u|/du=u/|u|?

Comment: Were do you find that?

Comment: written in solution JAN